# black screen simulator on xcode 11.2.1

Tags: ios, xcode, simulator, xcode11.2.1

i installed xcode 11.2.1 , trying to lean some new thing (xcode and ios app development ) i tried to creat a simple app (the Side Menu of an app), after trying to run the app, the screen turns black and doesn't show my app.
before writhing this question i've tried several suggested solutions like reset the content and the sitting on the simulator but it didn't work, i hope somebody can help me 
thank you
[this is the containercontroller screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nd8gg.jpg)

Comment: You could try what happens when you add `view.backgroundColor = .white`.

Answer (score 2):

A black screen happens e.g.: if your app doesn't have an "entry point", thats the point (`UIViewController`) your app starts.

Here is an example how to set this:

1. Make sure that the right `Storyboard` is set in the project configuration:
   [image]
2. Make sure that within the selected `Storyboard`, there is an `Initial ViewController`:
   [image]

After you performed these steps, your app show the `Initial ViewController` right after the app started:
[image]

Comment: i've tried your solution but it did't work for me, i had to start from scratch, and do everything, not th way i want but so far so good considering my experience.